# React-Redux problem with update operation

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing a crud app with react-redux, i have successfully implement `read` and `add` operation, also i am in half way of `update` operation, when i click on edit button, i get data filled in form, only problem with update operation. I am using same form for both `update` and `add` I am facing problem only `dispatching` update data, it showing update data in table.

this is my `form.js` file:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: this.props.selectedData.name, age: this.props.selectedData.age, email: this.props.selectedData.email};
        this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit(event) {
        const data = {
            name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age, email: this.state.email
        };
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', data})
    }

    onHandleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(prevProps.selectedData.email !== this.props.selectedData.email){  //Check on email, because email is unique
          this.setState({name: this.props.selectedData.name, age: this.props.selectedData.age, email: this.props.selectedData.email})
        }
     }



    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.name} name="name" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.age} name="age" type="number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.email}  name="email" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <button onClick={(event) => this.submit(event)} type="button">
                    {this.props.isEdit ? 'Update' : 'SAVE' }
                </button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null)(Form);
```

and this is `table.js` file

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Table extends React.Component {
    onEdit = (item) => {  //Use arrow function to bind `this`
        this.props.selectedData(item);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => this.onEdit(item)}>EDIT
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ employees: state.employees });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Table);
```

and this is my `postReducer.js` file:

```
var initialState = {
  employees: [{name: 'jhon', age: '23', email: 'a@a'}, {name: 'doe', age: '24', email: 'b@a'}] 
};

var postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_POST':
        return {
          ...state,
          employees: [...state.employees, action.data],
        };
      case 'EDIT_POST':
        //return
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };


export default postReducer;
```

and this is `App.js` file

```
import React from "react"
import Table from "./table"
import Form from '../components/form'

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           selectedData: {name: '', age: '', email: ''},
           isEdit: false
        };
    }

    selectedData = (item) => {
       this.setState({selectedData: item,isEdit:true})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>   
              <Form selectedData={this.state.selectedData} isEdit={this.state.isEdit}/>          
            <table>
                <Table selectedData={this.selectedData} />
            </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

and this is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./components/App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import postReducer from '../src/postReducer'

const store = createStore(postReducer)


ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Everything is working great except update operation, Can anyone help me to achieve update operation? I tried a lot and failed to achieve this.

Comment: Your reducer doesn't have anything for update action?

Comment: In submit of your form component dispatch EDIT_POST or ADD_POST based on this.props.isEdit. `this.props.dispatch({type: this.props.isEdit?'EDIT_POST':'ADD_POST', data})` I would normally use a container with react redux connect and pass in action containers so your form only renders props and doesn't make dissensions about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to edit an employee you need some data that is fixed.

For example employee.id

Based on that you can lookup an employee and make the rest of the properties editable.

I added this inside your postReducer:

```
case 'EDIT_POST':
  return {
    ...state,
    employees: state.employees.map(emp => emp.id === action.data.id ? action.data : emp)
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kabwnx?file=postReducer.js).

Comment: This looks more like overwriting than editing. I'd assume if you edit you just want to apply changes to specific fields.

Comment: @Clarity how would you do it?

Comment: With object spread: employees: state.employees.map(emp => {
    if (emp.id === action.data.id) {
      emp = {
        ...emp,
        ...action.data
      }
    }
    return emp
  }
)

Comment: @Clarity overwriting the iterator variable "emp" seems a bit strange. How about this: `employees: state.employees.map(emp => emp.id === action.data.id ? {...emp, ...action.data } : emp)`